# Finding a nontrivial solutions in natural numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Consider  the equation for natural numbers $i,j,k,l:$
$$
(j^2-i^2) (k\cdot l)^2=2\, (l^2-k^2) (i\cdot j)^2.
$$
I am trying to prove that it has  no solution. To undertand  why, let us first  consider the  partial case $i=k=1.$ Then we have $(j^2-1)  l^2=2\, (l^2-1)  j^2$ or
$$
2=\frac{(j^2-1)  l^2}{(l^2-1)  j^2}=\frac{ l^2}{l^2-1  }-\frac{  l^2}{(l^2-1)  j^2} \leq \frac{ l^2}{l^2-1 } \leq \max \limits_l\frac{ l^2}{l^2-1  }=\frac{4}{3},
$$
and we get a contradiction. So there are no solutions for this  partial case.

How to prover( or disprove) it  for all   $i,j,k,l?$

Comment: with $j=i$ and $l=k$ both sides evaluate to $0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivially when $j=i$ and $l=k$ both sides evaluate to $0$

Less trivially I found (with a computer program) a lot of solutions, some of them evaluate to negative numbers (like the first one), some of them to positive one (like the last one).

Here are all the solutions with $1\le j,i,k,l\le 100$ and $i\ne j$, there are for numbers on each row that are the values for $i,j,k,l$, respectively

> 3 5 5 15
>   4 20 5 10
>   5 3 15 5
>   5 7 10 70
>   5 10 8 40
>   5 15 6 10
>   5 35 5 7
>   5 35 7 35
>   6 10 10 30
>   7 5 70 10
>   7 35 10 70
>   7 63 9 21
>   8 40 10 20
>   8 88 11 44
>   9 15 15 45
>   10 5 40 8
>   10 6 30 10
>   10 20 16 80
>   10 30 12 20
>   10 70 10 14
>   10 70 14 70
>   11 99 9 11
>   12 20 20 60
>   12 28 14 21
>   12 28 18 63
>   12 60 15 30
>   14 21 24 56
>   15 5 10 6
>   15 9 45 15
>   15 25 25 75
>   15 45 18 30
>   16 80 20 40
>   18 30 30 90
>   18 63 24 56
>   20 4 10 5
>   20 10 80 16
>   20 12 60 20
>   20 28 35 70
>   20 60 24 40
>   20 100 25 50
>   21 14 56 24
>   22 42 33 77
>   24 56 28 42
>   25 15 75 25
>   25 75 30 50
>   28 12 21 14
>   28 12 63 18
>   28 20 70 35
>   30 10 20 12
>   30 18 90 30
>   30 90 36 60
>   33 77 44 84
>   35 5 7 5
>   35 5 35 7
>   35 7 70 10
>   35 70 40 56
>   36 44 66 99
>   36 84 42 63
>   40 8 20 10
>   40 72 45 60
>   42 22 77 33
>   44 36 99 66
>   45 15 30 18
>   56 24 42 28
>   60 12 30 15
>   60 20 40 24
>   63 7 21 9
>   63 18 56 24
>   66 99 72 88
>   70 10 14 10
>   70 10 70 14
>   70 35 56 40
>   72 40 60 45
>   75 25 50 30
>   77 33 84 44
>   80 16 40 20
>   84 36 63 42
>   88 8 44 11
>   90 30 60 36
>   99 11 11 9
>   99 66 88 72
>   100 20 50 25

Comment: Thank you. The problem was   not hard as I saw.